# JPQL: Postgres entity is not recognized with TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a class that looks like this:

```
@Entity(name="DashboardWidget")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class DashboardWidget 
{
    public enum Type {USER_COUNT, ...};

    @Column(name="COMPANY_ID")
    protected Long companyId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    protected Type type;

    ...
```

There is no table behind this entity. The tables exist with each of the child class entities. These classes look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WIDGET_USER_COUNT")
public class UserCountWidget extends DashboardWidget 
{
    ...
```

With Spring Data JPA, I have the following in my repository:

```
List<DashboardWidget> findByCompanyId(Long companyId);
```

This works great and the List has instances of different child conrete classes. I then had a use case where I wanted just a `Set` of the `Type` enum so that I didn't have to load up the full entities. So, I added this to my Spring Data repository:

```
@Query("SELECT w.type FROM DashboardWidget w WHERE w.companyId = :companyId")
Set<DashboardWidget.Type> getWidgetTypes(@Param("companyId") Long companyId);
```

However, when this gets called, I get the following error:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "dashboardwidget" does not exist
  Position: 18
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT TYPE FROM DASHBOARDWIDGET WHERE (COMPANY_ID = ?)
    bind => [8888810010000000000]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=DashboardWidget sql="SELECT TYPE FROM DASHBOARDWIDGET WHERE (COMPANY_ID = ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2738)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllReportQueryRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2675)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ReportQuery.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1215)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1751)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "dashboardwidget" does not exist
  Position: 18
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1007)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:642)
    ... 119 more
```

I don't know JPQL well enough to know if it's something with my query, or if there's some kind of magic Spring Data is doing to make the `findByCompanyId` method work. Is there anything I can do to make the `getWidgetTypes` method work?

Comment: Looks like a bug as Eclipselink is querying over the DashboardWidget descriptor.  What EclipseLink version are you using?

Comment: @Chris Eclipselink version 2.5.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you created table with quotes, but trying to query it without them. Postgres is [case-insensitive for unquoted identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html). If this is the case, you need to consider quotes and use smth like `@Entity(name="\"DashboardWidget\"")` and `@NamedQueries` in order to not to mess with case sensitivity.

Good practice in general is not to use quotes for tables in psql, unless you have decent reason for it.

Comment: I do not have a table with quotes. There is no DashboardWidget table. That's why it's blowing up. It's trying to query a table that doesn't exist. My question is how to write the JPQL so it knows to query the tables used by the child classes/entities. Spring Data is making it work somehow.